# Not able to resize JPanel dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grouplayout

I am using `GroupLayout` and I have a `MainPanel`. In that, I have a header, a footer, 2 other `JPanel`s and a button.

I want to hide/show **panel1** whenever I click that button. I am using `setVisibility()` function on **panel1** to do that. Everything is working fine but I want to resize **panel2** to fit the width of the frame whenever **panel1** is hidden.

I tried using `setSize()` and `setPreferredSize()` functions, then used `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the **mainPanel** but still it does not work.

Comment: Try to pass the value to the constructor on panel2 where u will set the size of the panel2. I hope this will do good

Comment: _I tried using setSize()_ Bad idea since the LayoutManager's will overwrite that. _... setPreferredSize()_ Very bad idea, leave that to LayoutManager's too. You are probably not using the appropriate LayoutManager for your situation. Edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It is very hard to debug code without seeing it.